# Groovy: Building the XML from Closure Object

Tags: java, xml, groovy

I am building XML from object something like this:

```
def buildRequestParameters()
        {
            def requestParametersXML = {
                RequestParameters {
                    IgnoreEditWarnings("false")
                    Type("SaveWithoutValidation")
                    ContractNumber("")
                    Date("null")
                    Status("null")
                    RecordHTTPRequest("false")
                }
            }

            def requestParameters = StreamingMarkupBuilder.bind(requestParametersXML)
            return requestParameters
        }
```

Before binding it to StreamMarkupBuilder, I need to add another `element/node` to this object.
How can I update and access closure object elements?

```
if(someCondition)
{
  Add another element to RequestParameters //???
} 
def requestParameters = StreamingMarkupBuilder.bind(requestParametersXML)
```

> Note: Today is my second day with Groovy

Comment: How do you know the nodes you need to add?

Comment: Request XML is predefined. So lets say if `<Element1><Element11>text</Element1>` is coming from UI. It will go after `RequestParameters.Status`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a conditional while building the xml:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def buildRequestParameters(params)
{
    def requestParametersXML = {
        RequestParameters {
            IgnoreEditWarnings("false")
            Type("SaveWithoutValidation")
            ContractNumber("")
            Date("null")
            Status("null")
            if (params.Element1) {
              Element1 {
                Element11( params.Element1.Element11 )
              }
            }
            RecordHTTPRequest("false")
        }
    }

    def requestParameters = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind(requestParametersXML)
    return requestParameters
}

println buildRequestParameters( [:] )

println buildRequestParameters( [Element1: [Element11: "element11 value"]] )
```

Comment: If I am accessing requestParametersXML from some other method. How would I add `Element1` there?

Comment: I'm not aware of a solution to insert a method call between others (which is how xml nodes in groovy are created). Why don't you delay the xml declaration to the last moment and keep passing parameters? Is that possible? If it isn't, maybe we can try something using maps.